# Best practice: Solution References

Tags: tfs

We use Team Foundation Server for project management.
Say we have a structure like:

```
Root
  ProjA
  SuiteB
    Bin
    SubProj1
    SubProj2
    SuiteB.sln <-- Contains both SubProj
  ProjC
    Bin
```

ProjA is a library which contains common code used in most of our applications.
And it needs to be referenced in SubProj1, SubProj2 and ProjC

Currently inside each main folder I have a 'Bin' where we have checked in a copy of ProjA.dll.

This works, but ProjA changes often and once ProjA is updated, other projects should look to use the new ProjA especially if bugs are fixed. ( we do keep ProjA backwards compatible)

We keep forgetting to change/update the dll's in the Bin folders, plus we now have upwards of 30 projects all referencing ProjA so theres quite a few of them that have to change when an update occurs.

**Is there a better way than yelling at programmers who forget to update the dll in projects they are working on?**

Note - Its hard to track across 30 people when ProjA changes, i.e. People keep claiming they didn't know an update was made, even though emails are sent out.

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is: If you're putting binaries in source control, you're doing something wrong.

Either use project references to your shared projects (so each individual application builds the shared projects as necessary), or version your binaries using a package manager like NuGet, and let NuGet handle restoring the appropriate version of the binary reference at build time.